# Wrong cosine function graph in Manim

Tags: python, manim

How can I edit my code to make the graph in my Manim code similar to the actual graph of the function cos(1/x)?

Actual graph:
[image: Actual Graph]

```
from manim import *
from numpy import cos, sqrt

class CreateGraph(GraphScene):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        GraphScene.__init__(
            self,
            x_min=-5,
            x_max=5,
            y_min=-5,
            y_max=5,
            graph_origin=ORIGIN,
            axes_color=GREEN)

def construct(self):
    # Create Graph
    self.setup_axes(animate=True)
    f1 = self.get_graph(lambda x: cos(1/x) , x_min=-4, x_max=4)
    
    # Construct the Figures
    self.play(ShowCreation(f1))
    self.wait(1)
```

Graph from Manim:
[image: Graph from Manim]

Answer (score 1):

Since `cos(1/x)` isn't really defined at `0`, try this:

`f1 = self.get_graph(lambda x: cos(1/x), discontinuities=[inverse_interpolate(self.x_min, self.x_max, 0)])`

Edit as per your liking. It basically tells manim to not render the graph for `cos(1/x)` at `x=0`.